# How to add multiple input search in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook, drupal-modules

I am new in Drupal. I want to add multiple input search in my website.

For example Find Hotels by Name, Country, State, Location etc

How can i add these filter in my drupal website. Is their any module available??? Please give me some pointers.

Comment: Do you want to have a cck field with two values or two diffrent search options ?

Comment: I want search like in drupal website http://drupal.org/project/modules where anyone can search module by category, compatibility, status, name etc. I want to follow same search in my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can create view with exposed filters, each exposed filter will be separate input search filter. In this case you also can add proper indexes in your DB to make it faster.

Comment: Well, default views module can provide you with enough functions. But seems this module can extend it and give you more flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check 'exposed filters' in Views.